# Include php file in yii1

Tags: php, yii

I need include files in a cycle and get methods from that files.
I know about Yii:: import function but she doesn't work correctly in my case.
I have trying several times did that:

```
  require_once Yii::app()->basePath . "/modules/$module->url_name/controllers/$file";
```

But this code gives me only "internal server error". 
If instead variables I put real name of module and name of the file - all works fine.
Where is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could be instead you should use $module->basePath

```
require_once(  $module->basePath . "/controllers/" .$file);
```

Comment: I want obtain /protected/modules/moduleName/controllers/nameOfController.php. As for  $module->basePath  - what mean this property?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModule#basePath-detail this if for $module->basePath